# asp:RequiredFieldValidator causing extra line in aspx page

Tags: asp.net, css, textbox, formatting, requiredfieldvalidator

I have simple ASPX page with few text buttons/drop downs. For almost every text button/drop down, I have the validators.

Issue I am facing is each of these validators produce a blank line on the page. Below is sample of the code in ASPX page. I tried with adding DISPLAY=DYNAMIC but I see blank lines getting reduced but when the validator message (or required * mark) is shown it shows that is not relevant near the textboxes.

```
            <tr>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="CityValidator" meta:resourceKey="CityValidator"
                ValidationGroup='<%# ValidationGroupName %>'  ControlToValidate="CityTextBox">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <td>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="CityTextBox" MaxLength='30' CssClass="TextBox" />
            </td>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="RegionCodeValidator" meta:resourceKey="RegionCodeValidator"
                        ValidationGroup='<%# ValidationGroupName %>' ControlToValidate="RegionCodeTextBox" >*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <td>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="RegionCodeTextBox" MaxLength='2' CssClass="TextBox"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the validator display as dynamic.  You should also put the validators within the table structure to keep your HTML structure valid.

```
   <tr>
        <td>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="CityValidator" meta:resourceKey="CityValidator" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup='<%# ValidationGroupName %>'  ControlToValidate="CityTextBox">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="CityTextBox" MaxLength='30' CssClass="TextBox" />
        </td>
        <td>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="RegionCodeValidator" meta:resourceKey="RegionCodeValidator" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup='<%# ValidationGroupName %>' ControlToValidate="RegionCodeTextBox" >*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="RegionCodeTextBox" MaxLength='2' CssClass="TextBox"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: @J Torres: thanks for the input. As mentioned in my original post, when I put display=dynamic, the messages or (red *) do not display correctly near the relevant textbuttons/dropdowns. Please suggest.

Comment: What do you mean by "display correctly"?  Are they not inline?  Where would you like them versus where they are? Do you have any styling on td's where contained elements are cleared/block?